# How can I perform a "match or create" operation in py2neo v3?

Tags: python, database, neo4j, py2neo

I want to create a Node/Relationship only if a Node/Relationship with the same attribute**s** doesn't already exist in the graph. If they do, I would like to fetch the relevant item.

Right now I am doing something that I suppose is both unidiomatic and inefficient. Assuming each `Person` node has a unique pair (`name`, `age`), I do something like this:

```
try:
    node = graph.data('MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name = {name} AND'
                      'n.age = {age} RETURN n LIMIT 1',
                      name=my_name, age=my_age)[0]['n']
except IndexError:
    node = Node('Person', name=my_name, age=my_age)
```

To my understanding [`find_one()`](http://py2neo.org/v3/database.html#py2neo.database.Graph.find_one) works only if you have just one property to search for, and [`match_one()`](http://py2neo.org/v3/database.html#py2neo.database.Graph.match_one) allows no properties for relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Cypher [MERGE](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-merge) clause to perform a "match or create":

```
node = graph.data('MERGE (n:Person) WHERE n.name = {name} AND'
                  'n.age = {age} RETURN n LIMIT 1',
                  name=my_name, age=my_age)[0]['n']
```

py2neo does have [merge](http://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html#py2neo.Graph.merge) and [merge_one](http://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html#py2neo.Graph.merge_one) functions, but they only take a single property, so using Cypher would be the more general approach.